# C# Sintaxis de Arreglos de Arreglos

Tags: c#

Estamos viendo arreglos multidimensionales y pude entenderlos, pero no puedo encontrar la sintaxis para un arreglo de arreglo, quiero un arreglo de arreglo de 3 dimensiones por ej

```
int[][][] tabla = new int[][][];
```

y quiero acceder a un elemento de su tercera dimension como lo hago aca doy un ejemplo pero con arreglo multidimensional necesitaria algo asi pero con arreglo de arreglo.

```
//arreglo multi

int[,,] matriz2 = {   
    { {1,1,1 },{1,1,1 },{1,1,1 } },  
    { {2,2,2},{3,2,88},{4,3,3 } },  
    { {2,3,3 }, {2,2,2 }, {2,2,4 } }
};
Console.WriteLine(matriz2[1,1,2]); // salida 88
```

Añado un ejemplo de arreglo de arreglo de 2 dimensiones

```
 //arreglo de arreglo
        int[][] tabla = new int[3][];
        tabla[0] = new int[1] {1 };
        tabla[1] = new int[2] {2,2};
        tabla[2] = new int[2] { 3, 3 };




        Console.WriteLine(tabla[2][0]); // Salida 3
```

quiero saber como hacerlo de 3 dimensiones y accerder a un elemento de la 3ra dimension.

aca dejo la base de como seria 3 dimensiones

```
int[][][] tabla = new int[][][];
```

Comment: Con `[1,1,2]` le estás indicando que quieres coger el segundo elemento `{2,2,2},{3,2,88},{4,3,3 } ` (el primero seria indice 0), y del segundo elemento quieres coger el segundo elemento `{3,2,88}` y de éste coger el 3ero `88`. Cual es tu pregunta? Un saludo

Comment: Estamos viendo arreglos multidimensionales (el cual si entiendo, por eso puse el ejemplo) y tambien estamos viendo arreglos de arreglos(el cual no entiendo), necesito conocer la sintaxis en un equivalente parecido al que puse en el arreglo multidimensional PERO en arreglo de arreglo.

Comment: //arreglo de arreglo
            int[][] tabla = new int[3][];
            tabla[0] = new int[1] { 1 };
            tabla[1] = new int[2] { 2,2 };
            

            Console.WriteLine(tabla[0][0]);//salida 1 quiero hacer algo como esto pero con [][][] y acceder a un elemento cualquiera de la tercer dimesion, puedo entenderlo con 2dimesiones pero tengo un problema de sintaxis para la tercer dimension me esta  faltando  algo y es parte de la sintaxis.

Comment: Veo que ya te contestaron, pero igual te dejo un link con unos cuantos ejemplos: http://www.javacamp.org/javavscsharp/arraytype.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede convertir a una sintaxis de arreglo de arreglos de la siguiente manera:

```
int[][][] matriz2 = new int [][][] {   
    new int [][] { new int[] {1,1,1}, new int[] {1,1,1}, new int[] {1,1,1} },  
    new int [][] { new int[] {2,2,2}, new int[] {3,2,88}, new int[] {4,3,3} },  
    new int [][] { new int[] {2,3,3}, new int[] {2,2,2}, new int[] {2,2,4} }
};
Console.WriteLine(matriz2[1][1][2]); // salida 88
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/MHG91567)</kbd>

Pero como puedes ver, la sintaxis no es tan compacta como la otra, porque debes incluir `new int[][][]`, `new int[][]` y `new int[]` a todos los niveles de la expresión que inicializa el arreglo de arreglos.

Y, por supuesto, el otro cambio es la forma de acceder al `88` con `matriz2[1][1][2]` en vez de `matriz2[1,1,2]`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Satan, con razon no lograba crear una 3ra dimension en esa sintaxis, es bastante compleja, sabia que tenia problema en el entendimiento de la sintaxis muchisimas gracias!

Comment: @Shiki Si te sirvió la respuesta no olvides de marcarla como respuesta aceptada